# I cannot create dynamic web application in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I cannot create new dynamic web application in eclipse.If i click new project from file menu it is not displaying "dynamic web application" option.It is not showing the option "web".I am running eclipse 3.4.0.

Can anyone give help on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see this kind of "new Project" feature:

[image]
<sub>(source: [viralpatel.net](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/eclipse-new-project-struts-example.png))</sub>

, could you check:

- if you have [WTP installed](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsf/dev_resource/JSFTutorial-RC3/JSFTools_tutorial.html) with your eclipse configuration ?
- in what perspective you currently are ? (try 'Java' or better yet 'J2EE' as mentioned in this ["Build Web applications with Eclipse, WTP, and Derby"](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0509cline/) IBM article)

Comment: I am currently in j2ee perspective.

Comment: So... in J2EE perspective, with WTP installed and... no "Dynamic Web Project" in sight ?

Comment: No.WTP is not installed.If i try to install WTP via software updates from help menu it is giving 100 lines of error like "repository not found".

Comment: Thanks a lot VonC.I solved that problem.I copied the plugins folder from my colleague system and i pasted in my system.Thanks for good link u given.

Comment: Cool, you found the solution! Glad I could help

Answer (score 6):

You need the **Java EE Devleoper Tools** to create **Dynamic Web Projects**

- Go to Help->Install New Software.
- In the dropdown, select 'Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno'
- Expand 'Web, XML, Java EE, and OSGI Enterprise Development'
- Check the box for 'Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools'

Once installed, you can create a New -> Other -> Dynamic Web Project

Comment: nice explain answer +1

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for the step by step walkthrough.